# what are these endings: -о and ие?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

I couldn't understand the suffixes(endings) of the words written in **bold** in the following sentence.

э́то мои́ но́вые **Англо**-**ру́сские** словари́.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Англо-ру́сские словари́

The adjective "англо-русский" is a **single** word. Therefore it has only one ending "-ий" (pl. "-ие"). Its first part should not be declined. The same holds with "русско-английские словари", for example.

But if it's written in two separate words then both are to be declined: "английские и русские словари" (note that it means a totally different thing though).

Comment: thank you for the explanation. But what about the -о ending in русско? what is that and what is it used for?

Comment: @xpr34 Technically this "о" is not an ending. It's a special "connecting vowel" which is used to paste both adjectives together.

Comment: @xpr34 -o- here is the connecting vowel, like in "thermodynamics", "thermonuclear", "psychosomatic", "astrophysics", "Russo-Japanese", "Afro-American", "Anglo-French".

Comment: A good question.

Comment: @xpr34 You may find 3 connecting vowels used in Russian words -о-, -е-, -у-

Answer (score -1):

It means dictionary translate from English to Russian.`Русско-английский` - translate from Russian to English.
`Англо-русский словарь` - one diсtionary
`Англо-русские словари` - many dictionaries

Comment: Have you read the question?